# Why doesn't interrupt TIMER0_COMPA work with loops?

Tags: c++, interrupt

I need have two stepping motors working at the same time each with a different number of steps. But loops (`for`, `while`) don't work with this task using type of interrupt above. What is wrong?

[image: Screenshot of update function]

My code:

```
class Driver {
    int pinStep;
    long times;
    int state;
    unsigned long previousTime;

  public:
    Driver(int pin, long interval) {
      pinStep = pin;
      pinMode(pinStep, OUTPUT);
      times = interval;
      state = LOW;
      previousTime = 0;
    }

    void update(unsigned long currentTime) {
      int iteration;
      while ((iteration < 5) & (currentTime - previousTime >= times)) {
        previousTime = currentTime;
        if (state == LOW) {
          state = HIGH;
        } else {
          state = LOW;
        }
        digitalWrite(pinStep, state);
        iteration++;
      }
    }
};

Driver drv1(5, 2);
Driver drv2(7, 50);

// set timer behavior
void setup() {
  OCR0A = 0x80; // 128
  TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);
}

// interrupt handler
SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  drv1.update(currentTime);
  drv2.update(currentTime);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: Try moving both instantiations of `Driver` into volatile memory - `voltatile Driver drv1(5, 2);` - and again for `drv2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void update(unsigned long currentTime) {
      int iteration;
      while ((iteration < 5)
```

Your code take a variable with an undefined value (`iteration`) and loops while it is less than 5. How is this useful? Perhaps set iteration to zero:

```
      int iteration = 0;
```

---

> But cycles (for, while) don't work with this task using type of interrupt above.

Please define what "don't work" means here. It does too much? Too little? Nothing at all?

---

> And Serial.print prints out iteration value as "111111"

The only way that could happen is if `currentTime - previousTime >= times` is false. Which it would be.

```
  while ((iteration < 5) & (currentTime - previousTime >= times)) {
```

Do you mean: `currentTime - previousTime < times`?

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
I initialized iteration variable as zero but loop doesn't work correctly: stepping motor is moving all the time, not on certain steps (5). And Serial.print prints out iteration value as "111111" See screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1uyPO.jpg

Comment: I don't see any `Serial.print` in your code.